# Kotlin's crossinline keyword

Tags: kotlin

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38827186/780350) but I have a more fundamental question regarding the `crossinline` keyword.  I'm not really sure what problem it is solving and how it solves it.

From [the Kotlin Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#non-local-returns),

> Note that some inline functions may call the lambdas passed to them as parameters not directly from the function body, but from another execution context, such as a local object or a nested function. In **such cases**, non-local control flow is also not allowed in the lambdas. **To indicate that**, the lambda parameter needs to be marked with the crossinline modifier:

[Emphasis added]

This statement is ambiguous to me.  First, I am having trouble actually picturing what is meant by "such cases".  I have a general idea of what the issue is but can't come up with a good example of it.

Second, the phrase "To indicate that," can be read multiple ways.  To indicate what?  That *a particular case* is not allowed?  That it *is* allowed?  That non-local control flow in a given function definition is (or is not) allowed?

In short, I have trouble figuring out what the context for using this really is, what using it communicates to clients, and what the expected results of applying this keyword are.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> First, I am having trouble actually picturing what is meant by "such cases". I have a general idea of what the issue is but can't come up with a good example of it.

Here's an example:

```
interface SomeInterface {
    fun someFunction(): Unit
}

inline fun someInterfaceBy(f: () -> Unit): SomeInterface { 
    return object : SomeInterface {
        override fun someFunction() = f() 
        //                            ^^^
        // Error: Can't inline 'f' here: it may contain non-local returns. 
        // Add 'crossinline' modifier to parameter declaration 'f'.
    }
}
```

<sup>Here, the function that is passed to `someInterfaceBy { ... }` is inlined inside an anonymous class implementing `SomeInterface`. Compilation of each call-site of `someInterfaceBy` produces a new class with a different implementation of `someFunction()`.</sup>

To see what could go wrong, consider a call of `someInterfaceBy { ... }`:

```
fun foo() {
    val i = someInterfaceBy { return }
    // do something with `i`
}
```

Inside the inline lambda, [`return` is non-local](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html) and actually means *return from `foo`*. But since the lambda is not called and leaks into the object `i`, *return from `foo`* may be absolutely meaningless: what if `i.someFunction()` (and thus the lambda) is called after `foo` has already returned or even in a different thread?

Generically, *'such cases'* means `inline` functions that call their functional parameters not in their own bodies (effectively, i.e. taking other inline functions into account) but inside some other functions they declare, like in non-inline lambdas and anonymous objects.

---

> Second, the phrase "To indicate that," can be read multiple ways. To indicate what? That a particular case is not allowed? That it is allowed? That non-local control flow in a given function definition is (or is not) allowed?

This is exactly how the problem I described above is fixed in the Kotlin language design: whenever an `inline` function intends to inline its functional parameter somewhere where it could be not called *in-place* but stored and called later, the parameter of the `inline` function should be marked as `crossinline`, indicating that non-local control flow is not allowed in the lambdas passed here.

Comment: So the `crossinline` keyword prevents a lambda from containing a `return` keyword (resulting in a non-local return) which would have no deterministic meaning from the way the lambda is used in the function.

Comment: I would also assume that return at labels is not affected by the use of `crossinline`, correct?

Comment: @melston, yes, as long as it is *local*. That is, `someList.forEach { item -> someCrossInline { return@forEach item } }` is not allowed, because that's a non-local return for the `crossinline` lambda, but `someList.forEach { item -> someCrossInline { return@someCrossInline item } }` is fine (sorry for large code in a comment).

Comment: As an addition, think of in suspend function.

Answer (score 35):

### Problem: non-local `return`

Let's first understand the problem of non-local `return` with a simple example:

```
fun doSomething() {
    println("Before lambda")
    doSomethingElse {
        println("Inside lambda")
        return // This is non-local return
    }
    println("After lambda")
}

inline fun doSomethingElse(lambda: () -> Unit) {
    println("Do something else")
    lambda()
}
```

**Non-local `return`**

In the code above, the `return` statement is called a *non-local return* because it's not local to the function in which it is called. This means this `return` statement is local to the `doSomething()` function and not to the lambda function in which it is called. So, it terminates the current function as well as the outermost function.

**Local `return`**

If you just wanted to return from the lambda, you would say `return@doSomethingElse`. This is called *local return* and it is local to the function where it is specified.

**Problem**

Now the problem here is that the compiler skips the lines after the non-local `return` statement. The decompiled bytecode for the `doSomething()` looks like following:

```
public static final void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("Before lambda");
    System.out.println("Doing something else");
    System.out.println("Inside lambda");
}
```

Notice that there is no statement generated for the line `println("After lambda")`. This is because we have the non-local `return` inside the lambda and the compiler thinks the code after the `return` statement is meaningless.

---

### Solution: `crossinline` keyword

**`crossinline`**

In **such cases** (like the problem mentioned above), the solution is to disallow the non-local `return` inside the `lambda`. To achieve this, we mark the `lambda` as `crossinline`:

```
inline fun doSomethingElse(crossinline lambda: () -> Unit) {
    println("Doing something else")
    lambda()
}
```

**Non-local `return` disallowed**

When you use the `crossinline` keyword, you are telling the compiler, "give me an error, if I accidentally use a non-local `return` inside the nested functions or local objects.":

```
fun doSomething() {
    println("Before lambda")
    doSomethingElse {
        println("Inside lambda")
        return                  // Error: non-local return
        return@doSomethingElse  // OK: local return
    }
    println("After lambda")
}
```

Now the compiler generates the bytecode as expected:

```
public static final void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("Before lambda");
    System.out.println("Doing something else");
    System.out.println("Inside lambda");
    System.out.println("After lambda");
}
```

---

That's it! Hope I made it easier to understand.

Comment: I don't think the example code demonstrates the problem... It _would_ be a problem if the `doSomethingElse` function had more statements after calling `lambda`, and the non-local `return` caused those to be unexpectedly skipped. But the example only has statements after a `return` in the `doSomething` function, and skipping statements after a `return` is completely expected. In other words, in the current example the `doSomethingElse` function doesn't have a reason to care whether the passed lambda is `crossinline` or not.